# How to get the text displayed on a button in C#?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I am currently making a simple calculator app for the iPhone using Xamarin.iOS. I have tried doing `Button click = (Button)sender;` but it seems like it does not work. It keeps saying that 'Button' could not be found even though I have set that name in the storyboard.

This is what I have so far (I am writing this in my ViewController.cs file):

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace app1
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public string[] number = new string[2];

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


            Button1.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {

                Button click = (Button)sender;


            };
        }
        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public void UpdateDisplay() {
            DisplayValue.Text = $"{number[0]} {number[1]} {number[2]}";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Button` as you use it, is a type name, ie you are casting your sender to a variable  `click` of type `Button`. But the respective type in Xamarin.iOS is called `UIButton` See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/buttons) for details

```
UIButton click = (UIButton)sender;
```